# How to get host cpu usage in k8s pod?

Tags: python, kubernetes

I want to get a host(in k8s cluster) cpu usage, I want to deploy a pod in this host, and in the pod, I want to get this host cpu usage.

Yes, I know. we can using below method, but don't want.

```
kubectl top [flags] [options]
```

The psutil library gives information about CPU, RAM, etc, but in the pod, it just give pod how many resource used.

Comment: A Pod (and containers more generally) is isolated from its host environment in several ways; you probably _can't_ find this out, and if you have many more Nodes than replicas of your Deployment, it's not going to be especially meaningful.  Why do you want this number; what do you plan to do with it?